# Plot3D, Constraints and Intersections

Tags: plotting

I was wondering if it is possible to start from the following piece of code

```
a = Plot3D[ x y, {x,0,10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotTheme-> "Business"];
b = Graphics3D[InfinitePlane[{ 2, 6,0}, {{0, 0, 1}, {2, -2, 0}}]];

Show[a,b]
```

To obtain what follows:
– a more opaque curve;
– a line that emphasizes the intersection between the constraint and the curve;
– a line that emphasizes the level curve on the curve that corresponds to the one where the maximum is achieved.

Possibly, everything with Manipulate on some parameter over the Plot3D, e.g., $ax y$.

Thanks a lot in advance for any feedback!

Comment: What have you tried so far in pursuit of your objectives?

Comment: @MarcoB Good question! I can handle the manipulate and the opacity parts (both are pretty straightforward), but, in all earnesty, I am completely at loss regarding the rest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intersection curve has the equation:

```
f[x_]= {x, 8 - x, x (8 - x)}
```

And its maximum is:

```
x (8-x) /. Solve[D[x (8 - x),x]==0,x]

{16}
```

Therefore, we may choose a mesh line in the first plot of 16. For the intersection curve we make an additional plot:

```
a = Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Business", 
   Mesh -> {{16}}, MeshStyle -> Green];
b = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], 
    InfinitePlane[{2, 6, 0}, {{0, 0, 1}, {2, -2, 0}}]}];
c = ParametricPlot3D[{x, 8 - x, x (8 - x)}, {x, 0, 8}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];

Show[a, b, c]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Needless to write, it works like a charm. One thing, though. I thought I could handle the opacity of the infinite plane, but apparently this is not the case. I am putting Opacity[0.5] right in between the two closing square brackets, but nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I added Opacity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, I see how it works.